# EncryptedSharedPreferences isUserAuthenticationRequired not working properly

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-biometric, encrypted-shared-preference, android-jetpack-security

I am using EncryptedSharedPreferences to store encrypted data.

```
val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this)
val hasFingerprint = biometricManager.canAuthenticate() == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS

val advanceSpec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
    "master_key",
    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
).apply {
    setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
    setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
    setKeySize(256)
    if(hasFingerprint){
        setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
        setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(1)
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
            setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(false)
        }
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
            setIsStrongBoxBacked(true)
            setUserConfirmationRequired(true)
        }
    }
}.build()

val masterKey = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(advanceSpec)
val preferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
    "TestPreferences",
    masterKey,
    applicationContext,
    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
)
```

Actually, I was missing the BiometricPrompt part. I thought that calling `setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` would automatically handle authenticating user. but we have to show the BiometricPrompt ourselves. `isUserAuthenticationRequired` only ensures that the key would only be activated when a user is authorized.

```
val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(
            activity,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity),
            object: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                    super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                    createSharedPreferences()
                }
            }
        )

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
```

But, there is a problem. It only throws the UserNotAuthenticatedException while creating the `EncryptedSharedPreferences`. After that we can perform read and write operations for as long as we need. It isn't taking into consideration the `setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(1)`.

Comment: Are you able to store and fetch the data in the created encrypted shared preference?

Comment: yes, I'm able to store and fetch the data.

Comment: Did you check if `hasFingerprint` is returning true?

Comment: yes it's returning true

Comment: For me, the code you wrote is throwing `UserNotAuthenticatedException` while trying to create the encryptedsharedpreference object, if I don't explicitly ask for a user to authenticate using a `BiometricPrompt` https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth . I am using a Smasung Galaxy M20 running android 10. 

But I am a little confused that it allows me to edit the sharedpreference once I have created its object even if I do the read and write operation beyond 1 second time of authentication.

Comment: yes I found that too

Comment: I don't know what was the issue before but It wasn't throwing any exception before

Comment: I found the reason why it does not require authentication post 1 second. It is because, once the encrypted shared preference is intiated, it loads the keys used to encrypt and decrypt the data in the memory and then those are used to access the data from the files. You can read the code inside Encrypted shared preference class. This is pretty evident.

Comment: yes I got that too. thanks

Comment: @Swapnil you can post this comment as the answer so that I can accept it and close this question

Comment: @IsmailShaikh, I was trying to use the same code as above ( using Builder now as MasterKeys is deprecated) , as you mentioned "It only throws the UserNotAuthenticatedException while creating the EncryptedSharedPreferences" , i'm facing it too, so are you just catching the exception and proceeding with using encryptedsharedpreference, for creating new keys and values in encryptedsharedpreference ?

Comment: No, when it throws an exception it means that the user is not authenticated. So, after catching the exception, just show a ```BiometricPrompt``` and create the ```EncryptedSharedPreferences``` in the ```onAuthenticationSucceeded(BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result)```callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason why it does not require authentication post 1 second. It is because, once the encrypted shared preference is intiated, it loads the keys used to encrypt and decrypt the data in the memory and then those are used to access the data from the files. You can read the code inside `EncryptedSharedPreference` class. This is pretty evident.

```
KeysetHandle daeadKeysetHandle = new AndroidKeysetManager.Builder()
                .withKeyTemplate(prefKeyEncryptionScheme.getKeyTemplate())
                .withSharedPref(context, KEY_KEYSET_ALIAS, fileName)
                .withMasterKeyUri(KEYSTORE_PATH_URI + masterKeyAlias)
                .build().getKeysetHandle();
        KeysetHandle aeadKeysetHandle = new AndroidKeysetManager.Builder()
                .withKeyTemplate(prefValueEncryptionScheme.getKeyTemplate())
                .withSharedPref(context, VALUE_KEYSET_ALIAS, fileName)
                .withMasterKeyUri(KEYSTORE_PATH_URI + masterKeyAlias)
                .build().getKeysetHandle();

        DeterministicAead daead = daeadKeysetHandle.getPrimitive(DeterministicAead.class);
        Aead aead = aeadKeysetHandle.getPrimitive(Aead.class);

        return new EncryptedSharedPreferences(fileName, masterKeyAlias,
                context.getSharedPreferences(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE), aead, daead);
```